# MQ under Delphi (IBM MA7Q SupportPac)

Tags: delphi, ibm-mq

I've been doing some research because I need to implement the MQ protocol under Delphi but the only interesting thing that I have found is that a long time ago it was a "SupportPac MA7Q" from IBM for this matter.

I managed to have these files under MA7Q (MQI.pas and MQIC.pas) but doing MQCONNX retrieves always an invalid login to the QM (I guess something is wrong or missing since these PAS files are so old).

So, finally, I am coming here in order to ask how would you proceed with this matter since it is being a headache to achieve the goal: communicate with MQ via Delphi.

Any idea, tip, or whatever would be appreciated.

---

Nowadays, I am facing a connection via MQIC.pas (downloaded from a MA7Q SupportPac I found) and I am having `Reason Code = 2035` connecting to my QM.

The QM I am trying to connect is made following this link:
https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-windows/

The actual code for the connection is the following:

```
QMgrName := '';
for i := 1 to Length(edtQmgrName.Text) do
  QMgrName[i-1] := AnsiChar(edtQmgrName.Text[i]);

SetMQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT(pom);

pom.ConnectionName := '';
for i := 1 to Length(edtConnName.Text) do
  pom.ConnectionName[i-1] := AnsiChar(edtConnName.Text[i]);

pom.QMgrName := '';
for i := 1 to Length(edtQmgrName.Text) do
  pom.QMgrName[i-1] := AnsiChar(edtQmgrName.Text[i]);

pom.ChannelName := '';
for i := 1 to Length(edtChnlName.Text) do
  pom.ChannelName[i-1] := AnsiChar(edtChnlName.Text[i]);

pom.UserIdentifier := AnsiString('app');
pom.Password := AnsiString('passw0rd');

ConnectOpts := MQCNO_DEFAULT;
ConnectOpts.ClientConnPtr := @pom;
ConnectOpts.ClientConnOffset := 0;

ConnectOpts.Version := MQCNO_VERSION_2;

MQCONNX ( @QMgrName, @ConnectOpts, @HConn, @Compcode, @Reason);
if CompCode <> MQCC_OK then
    ShowMessage( 'Connection Failed' );
```

I don't know what is wrong so I am having the whole time 2035.

After a brief reading, I have found that 2035 could be an exception or an unauthorized login failure (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q132560_.htm).

> **Common connection errors**  CHLAUTH rules are used to determine if a channel can be started, and they allow mapping, through MCAUSER to
> another user Id. If the channel can not be started, the following
> errors commonly occur:

1. RC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
2. RC 2059 MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE
3. AMQ4036 Access not permitted
4. AMQ9776: Channel was blocked by userid
5. AMQ9777: Channel was blocked
6. MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2035
7. MQJE036: Queue manager rejected connection attempt

What I don't understand is how to determine if it is a "NOT AUTHORIZED" or an "EXCEPTION".

Nevertheless, the question is:
Why I am having this 2035? Is something missing from the connection? Something missing in the QM to be configured?

Thanks!

---

**Edit with further information (03/11/2020 10:00)**

The log is saying right now that the user is not correctly authenticated.

The user in my code is '**app**' but is showing '"ö'

I am using the MQCSP structure but somehow is not being passed properly.

```
sUser := 'app'#0;
sPW := 'passw0rd'#0;
sec.StrucId := MQCSP_STRUC_ID;
sec.Version := MQCSP_CURRENT_VERSION;
sec.AuthenticationType := MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD;
sec.CSPUserIdPtr := @sUser;
sec.CSPUserIdLength := MQLONG(Length(sUser));
sec.CSPUserIdOffset := 0;
sec.CSPPasswordPtr := @sPW;
sec.CSPPasswordOffset := 0;
sec.CSPPasswordLength := MQLONG(Length(sPW));
ConnectOpts.SecurityParmsPtr := @sec;
```

Comment: "so old" - possibly, you can find another components there: https://github.com/search?q=MQ+language%3APascal&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Pascal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MQ under Delphi (MA7Q SupportPac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606706/mq-under-delphi-ma7q-supportpac).  Update the original as you have done, don't open a new question.

Comment: I opened a new one since it remains closed (my edit didn't change anything). Sorry for this :(

Comment: Authentication using fields in the MQCD only works if you've got a suitable security exit on the qmgr end of the connection. You need to use the MQCSP structure, but as I said in the other item, that's not defined in that old MA7Q file so you'd need to create that structure first.

Though that assumes it is authentication that's failing. Which you can confirm by looking at the qmgr error logs.

Comment: Please look in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG and find the error message that will explain what the reason behind the application being send 2035. Please update your question with what you find.

Comment: Now you're using the CSP, but have you set the Connectopts.Version so it will be recognised? MQCNO_VERSION_5 is minimum. And are the sUser and sPW variables of a suitable type so that the compiler deals with them as C strings? (Pchar I think)

Comment: Yeah, MCNO_VERSION_5 is being used. sUser and sPW are array of AnsiChar. The current problem is that, instead of "app" user, the MQ log says it is receiving "a". I have been comparing sizeof in C and Delphi structs and they are the same. Looks like the Length field is not working properly.

Comment: PAnsiChar(AnsiString('app')) worked and now I am connecting (having valid Handle, Code = 0 and Reason = 0). Now to keep moving :)

Comment: Thorba, please write up your changes in an answer so someone else may benefit in the future.  Also not sure if IBM released MA7Q on github, but if they did you could submit the changes there as well.

Comment: I'll update everything once I solve the encoding with GET function  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I posted in your other (duplicate) question: [MQ under Delphi (MA7Q SupportPac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606706/mq-under-delphi-ma7q-supportpac/64611841#64611841)

Questions:

- Is there a reason code from the MQCONNX API call for the "invalid login"?  i.e. 2035 - MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
- Are you using the correct UserId and Password for the server that the queue manager is running on?  If LDAP authentication, again, are you using the correct UserId and Password for the LDAP server?
- Did you or the MQAdmin grant your UserId permission to access the queue manager?  See  [setmqaut command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083500_.htm) in the MQ KnowLedge Center.

  setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -t qmgr -g {GROUP} +connect +inq +dsp

  setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n MYQ.ABC.** -t queue -g {GROUP} +allmqi +dsp
- What channel are you using?  Are you using a SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN channel?  which you should not be using.  Did you or the MQAdmin create a CHLAUTH rule to allow you to connect?

Finally, you should turn on queue manager 'Authority Events', then run your program.  Use a tool like [SupportPac MS0P](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ms0p-websphere-mq-explorer-%E2%80%93-extended-management-plug-ins-and-tools) or [MO71](https://mqgem.com/mo71.html) or even [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) to look at the event messages in the 'SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT' queue.  The event message(s) will tell you exactly what the permission issue is.